# Help me Check Cinelli Legit or Not

Tags: road-bike, frames

I am Dany from Indonesia, I want to buy a preloved Cinelli bike here, the series is Cinneli Experience 2018, but I am not sure if this bike is legit or not, because I can't find any info about this bike on the internet, can you help me check this bike?
I have attached photos of the bike.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's the frame material?  Carbon, aluminium, steel...?

Comment: @DavidW the seller said it's an alloy frame with a carbon fork

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Cinelli Experience usually has round tubing. It does't mean your bike is not a Cinelli, but it is not an Experience and it is not 2018.

Your frame has very distinctive tube shapes that Cinelli does and has used on various frames. Your bike also has carbon seatstays, which are very uncommon by 2018. The frame I see most often with that type of rear end is a Fuji that must be 10 or more years old. Other brands used the style between 2009 and 2013 but by then it was already becoming quite uncommon as there is not really an advantage to frame weight or comfort over the modern alu designs.

Your frame looks like it has had a very nice paint finish applied (that is not cheap!) and high quality decals fitted. The groupset is alot newer than the frame in my opinion, and will perform.

Perhaps something else from the cinelli lineup?

All the Cinellis that I have seen, bought and sold (five or more, of different ages) have the winged - C logo embossed into the frame or added onto it, as part of the metal. Often at the rear dropouts but sometimes elsewhere. Older models also had Italian threaded bottom brackets rather than BSC/British more common on other makes.

http://web.archive.org/web/20180525082803/http://cinelli.it/it/prodotti/experience-speciale/

A further note, all Cinelli aluminium and steel bikes are built with Columbus tubing and should have the Columbus tube decal telling you which tubeset is used, either on the seattube or sometimes the downtube. This will generally be missing if the frame has been repainted.

Comment: I agree, it's at least not a recent Cinelli frame; I couldn't find any bikes going back at least 5 years with that type merged seat stay.

Comment: Thank u so much for the answer sir @Noise